# Can't Run Delayed Job in the background on ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, delayed-job, daemons

`rake jobs:work` works just fine

But `RAILS_ENV=development ./script/delayed_job start` (or any of its permutations) doesn't work on 1.9.2. I can run it just fine on 1.9.1.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Without further information, we can't help much. What exactly do you mean when you say "doesn't work". The process does not starts, it's stars but fails without an error message, it starts but fails to start the jobs? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using collectiveidea's fork for your gem/plugin installation ? If not, please use it. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job